# Merging multiple count queries with a common date field

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 3 queries as per below :-

```
SELECT to_char(Actual_SSD,'YYYY-MM') AS Period, Count(Actual_SSD)
FROM tblQuotesNew
where tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status='Accepted'
group by to_char(Actual_SSD,'YYYY-MM')
order by to_char(Actual_SSD,'YYYY-MM')

SELECT to_char(requested_SSD,'YYYY-MM') AS Period, Count(requested_SSD)
FROM tblQuotesNew
where tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status='Accepted'
group by to_char(requested_SSD,'YYYY-MM')
order by to_char(requested_SSD,'YYYY-MM')

SELECT to_char(date_sent_to_registrations,'YYYY-MM') AS Period, Count(date_sent_to_registrations)
FROM tblQuotesNew
where tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status='Accepted'
group by to_char(date_sent_to_registrations,'YYYY-MM')
order by to_char(date_sent_to_registrations,'YYYY-MM')
```

Is there a way in Oracle to merge these into one query with 4 columns, with the left most column being the date, and the next 3 columns being the counts. In Access I would do this with a crosstab query, but I am not sure if it is possible in Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one way of doing it.

```
select coalesce ( act.period, req.period, reg.period) as period
       , act.act_count
       , req.req_count
       , reg.reg_count
from (SELECT to_char(Actual_SSD,'YYYY-MM') AS Period, 
             Count(Actual_SSD) as act_count
      FROM tblQuotesNew
      where tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status='Accepted'
      group by to_char(Actual_SSD,'YYYY-MM')) act
    full outer join 
    ( SELECT to_char(requested_SSD,'YYYY-MM') AS Period,
             Count(requested_SSD) as req_count
      FROM tblQuotesNew 
      where tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status='Accepted'
      group by to_char(requested_SSD,'YYYY-MM')) req
          on req.period = act.period
    full outer join 
    ( SELECT to_char(date_sent_to_registrations,'YYYY-MM') AS Period, 
            Count(date_sent_to_registrations) as reg_count
      FROM tblQuotesNew
      where tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status='Accepted'
      group by to_char(date_sent_to_registrations,'YYYY-MM') ) reg
          on reg.period = act.period

order by 1
```

This is close to your existing logic, and so should reproduce the results you get from the separate queries.

The full outer joins handle the situation when not every type of event happens in a given month. The `coalesce()` function takes the first non-null `period` from the subqueries.

Comment: @ APC This produced exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for the code and taking the time to explain it - really appreciated..